# Is there a bank or ATM in Pokemon Sun?

Tags: pokemon-sun-moon

Is there some kind of bank or ATM in Pokemon Sun? I have about 30,000 Poke dollars and I'm trying to save money without having that much in my pockets just in case I get defeated. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, there has never been a bank or ATM feature in any Pokémon game, other than letting your mother hold onto some of it in GSC, as noted by DanmakuGrazer.

This wouldn't really serve a practical purpose in Gen VII, though, as you don't pay a percentage of your money when you lose, as of FireRed and LeafGreen. The only thing affected by the amount of money you have is how much you can buy from Pokéshops.

From [Bulbapedia page on blacking out](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Black_out):

> Before Generation IV, half of the money on hand was lost and this loss was not explicitly stated to the player. In FireRed and LeafGreen and Generation IV onward, however, the money lost depends on the level of the player's Pokémon and the number of Badges he/she has earned. In these games, the player receives a message about how much was lost.

Comment: Your mom in GSC kinda did that, but not really.

Comment: I thought there was one in Pokemon Mystery Dungeon Red and Blue Rescue Team... I know there is a bank is there.

Comment: @Yoshi24517 yes but the mystery dungeon series is a spinoff series. The main series hasn't featured anything like this aside from allowing your mom to hold onto some of your earnings, as noted by DanmakuGrazer, and even then, it was only a feature in GSC.